# Changing or adding compiling options in cc-mode

Tags: compilation, c++, cc-mode

In `cc-mode`, when we go to compile, <kbd>M-x</kbd> followed by `compile`, the default option is `make -k`. If I hit the down arrow, I am told no defaults available.

Is it possible to add the option `g++ -Wall currentfile.cpp -o currentfile -std=c++14` to the default compile options where currentfile is filled in by the name of the `.cpp` program I am editing?

If it is too difficult to have the currentfile populate, would it be possible to have `g++ -Wall -std=c++14` come up? Then I can fill in `x.cpp -o x`. However, option is one is the most desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [University of Wyoming](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jlc/courses/4780/emacs/_emacs) I have been able to achieve the result with:

```
;; Make M-x compile smarter in order to guess language
(require 'compile)
(defvar compile-guess-command-table
  '((c-mode       . "gcc -Wall -g %s -o %s -lm")
    (c++-mode     . "g++ -Wall %s -o %s -std=c++14")
    (fortran-mode . "gfortran -C %s -o %s")
    ))

(defun compile-guess-command ()
  (let ((command-for-mode (cdr (assq major-mode
                                     compile-guess-command-table))))
    (if (and command-for-mode
             (stringp buffer-file-name))
        (let* ((file-name (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
               (file-name-sans-suffix (if (and (string-match "\\.[^.]*\\'"
                                                             file-name)
                                               (> (match-beginning 0) 0))
                                          (substring file-name
                                                     0 (match-beginning 0))
                                        nil)))
          (if file-name-sans-suffix
              (progn
                (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                (setq compile-command
                      (if (stringp command-for-mode)
                          ;; Optimize the common case.
                          (format command-for-mode
                                  file-name file-name-sans-suffix)
                        (funcall command-for-mode
                                 file-name file-name-sans-suffix)))
                compile-command)
            nil))
      nil)))


;; Add the appropriate mode hooks.
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook       (function compile-guess-command))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook     (function compile-guess-command))
(add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook (function compile-guess-command))
```

Additionally, this solution also adds support for C and Fortran which I left in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The manual has a very useful entry on this, with an example of setting it based on the current file. (use <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>  <kbd>v</kbd> compile-command)

> Sometimes it is useful for files to supply local values for this variable.
>   You might also use mode hooks to specify it in certain modes, like this:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
 (unless (or (file-exists-p "makefile")
         (file-exists-p "Makefile"))
   (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
    (concat "make -k "
        (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name))))))
```

Additionally, you can use `set-file-local-variable-prop-line` to save the compile command for a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Install `smart-compile` package inside Emacs.

add this into your `init.el` or `.emacs`

```
(require 'compile)
(setq compilation-last-buffer nil)
;; save all modified buffers without asking before compilation
(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)
(defun compile-again (ARG)
  "Run the same compile as the last time.

With a prefix argument or no last time, this acts like M-x compile,
and you can reconfigure the compile args."
  (interactive "p")
  ;; the following two lines create bug: split a new window every time
  ;; (if (not (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
  ;;      (split-window-below))
  (if (and (eq ARG 1) compilation-last-buffer)
      (recompile)
    (call-interactively 'smart-compile)))
(bind-key* "C-x C-m" 'compile-again)
;; create a new small frame to show the compilation info
;; will be auto closed if no error
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      `(("*compilation*" . ((name . "*compilation*")
                            ,@default-frame-alist
                            (left . (- 1))
                            (top . 0)))))
(setq compilation-finish-functions
      (lambda (buf str)
        (if (null (string-match ".*exited abnormally.*" str))
            ;;no errors, make the compilation window go away in a few seconds
            (progn
              (run-at-time
               "1 sec" nil 'delete-windows-on
               (get-buffer-create "*compilation*"))
              (message "No Compilation Errors!")))))
```

Use `C-x C-m` to compile your source code, If you are the first time to execute `C-x C-m`, it will ask you to change the default command (which is usually enough), otherwise it will execute the command you just used to compile directly and you have to use `C-u C-x C-m` to change the command if you want. If you got a `Makefile` inside the current directory, it will notice and prompt to ask whether you want to use it.

Maybe this answer is too much for your question, but please try it.